# comparison of loop and vectorization in matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, vectorization

let us consider following code for impulse function

```
function y=impulse_function(n);
y=0;
if n==0
    y=1;
end
end
```

this code

```
>> n=-2:2;
>> i=1:length(n);
>> f(i)=impulse_function(n(i));
>>
```

returns result

```
 f

f =

     0     0     0     0     0
```

while this code

```
>> n=-2:2;
>> for i=1:length(n);
f(i)=impulse_function(n(i));
end
>> f

f =

     0     0     1     0     0
```

in both case i is 1 2 3 4 5,what is different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is not defined to handle vector input.

Modify your impluse function as follows:

```
function y=impulse_function(n)
    [a b]=size(n);
    y=zeros(a,b);
    y(n==0)=1;
end
```

In your definition of impulse_function, whole array is compared to zero and return value is only a single number instead of a vector.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case you are comparing an array to the value 0. This will give the result [0 0 1 0 0], which is not a simple true or false. So the statement `y = 0;` will not get executed and f will be [0 0 0 0 0] as shown.

In the second you are iterating through the array value by value and passing it to the function. Since the array contains the value 0, then you will get 1 back from the function in the print out of f (or [0 0 1 0 0], which is an impulse).

You'll need to modify your function to take array inputs.

#### Perhaps this example will clarify the issue further:

```
cond = 0;
if cond == 0
    disp(cond) % This will print 0 since 0 == 0
end

cond = 1;
if cond == 0
    disp(cond) % This won't print since since 1 ~= 0 (not equal)
end

cond = [-2 -1 0 1 2];
if cond == 0
    disp(cond) % This won't print since since [-2 -1 0 1 2] ~= 0 (not equal)
end
```

Comment: wait  please   different  between first and second  what is?in first case also i am iterating using i is not?

Comment: I've changed my answer to clearly explain the issue, unlike the other two answers which aim to provide a solution without really explaining the problem. I believe my answer actually answers your question: which is "what is different?"

Answer (score 1):

You could define your `impulse function` simply as this one -

```
impulse_function = @(n) (1:numel(n)).*n==0
```

Sample run -

```
>> n = -6:4
n =
    -6    -5    -4    -3    -2    -1     0     1     2     3     4
>> out = impulse_function(n)
out =
     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0
```

Plot code -

```
plot(n,out,'o')    %// data points
hold on
line([0 0],[1 0])  %// impulse point
```

Plot result -

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can write an even simpler function:

```
function y=impulse_function(n);
y = n==0;
```

Note that this will return `y` as a type logical array but that should not affect later numerical computations.