# Octave element wise comparisons

Tags: octave

for a function

```
    function retval = my_comparison(value)
        if (value < 1) 
            retval = 0;
        else
            retval = 1;
        endif
    endfunction
```

How do ensure that that an element-by-element evaluation is performed if a matrix is passed as `value`?

For an input of `[0,1,2]` I would expect `[0,1,1]`

**Update**

This is the correct method

```
function retval =  my_comparison(value)    
  [a b] = size(value);    
  retval = zeros(a, b);    
  retval(value < 1) = 0;    
  retval(value >= 1) = 1;    
endfunction
```

Comment: `value >= 1` does what you want in a single line

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou that has identical behaviour. A single value returned

Comment: @CrisLuengo Yep, That does thanks. I'll update my submission. I was expecting an operator like what is done with element-wise arithmetic.

Comment: Do pay special attention to the answer that comes up at the bottom for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28982475/7328782 -- it matches what Tasos suggests above, and is comparable to an element-wise arithmetic operator (in fact, `<` is an element-wise comparison operator).

Comment: Thanks, but I fail to understand. The comparison operators didn't work as I expected. Clearly i'm expecting something wrong.